# Custom labels on range aggregation in kibana

Tags: customization, visualization, kibana

I would like to customize the labels for range aggregation in kibana 5.6.6:

[image: Bad labels]

With something like :

- Very short
- Short
- Medium
- Long
- Too long
- Way too long

With this kind of range:

[image: Range configuration]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to get this figured out?

Comment: Nope, sorry :( Still nothing!